# How can I adjust bootstrap4 breakpoints?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap to set break points, I want a certain image to be hidden on small devices, and appear as the screen gets bigger
so I used this code:

```
<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-block">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo image" class="brand">
</a>
```

I'm expecting the logo to appear at screen size of 768px, but it actually appears at 844px.
this goes for every element in the page.

I used chrome and fire fox and got the same problem, also the problem exists if I use sm or lg
what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-sm-none d-md-block">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo image" class="brand">
</a>
```

Hope, this is the solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely the problem is solved when I stopped using browser-sync, I really don't have any explanation for this